# Accessing properties of objects within a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, object, properties

I'm trying to use a property of individual object instances stored within a `List<T>` object, but I can't seem to access the properties directly.

I have an object (`sportsCarVehicle`) which stores a user-defined name (`strVehicleName`) (amongst other properties, but that's not important) within itself. The object is then stored within a `List<sportsCarVehicle>` object called `sportsCarVehicleStorage`.
I need to access every instance of `sportsCarVehicle` in `List<sportsCarVehicle>` and pass the value of `strVehicleName` to a combo box on a form.

I assume I'll need some kind to loop to cycle through each instance and pass the name to the combo box, but my main issue is not being able to access the property I need. The `sportsCarVehicle` instances have no reference-able name.
One more thing I should note: the constructor for `sportsCarVehicle` is called within the `sportsCarVehicleStorage.Add()` method.

Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Are you sure the properties you want to access are marked public?

Comment: Can you add some code to better understand your problem?

Comment: Are you expecting `sportsCarVehicleStorage.strVehicleName` to work (rather than something like `sportsCarVehicleStorage[i].strVehicleName` within a loop)?

Comment: and also strVehicleName is a horrible name for a property. Just `Name` would be lot shorter, and just as descriptive.

Comment: Oh wow. Now I feel stupid haha. Thanks, that was the problem (not being set to public) =P

Answer (score 2):

Cant you do this

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>{"Hello", "World"};

 int len = lst[0].Length;
```

Here `.Length` is a property of string. As long as that property is public we can access it.

In your case

```
List<sportsCarVehicle> sportsCarVehicleStorage = new List<sportsCarVehicle>();

// Some code to populate list.

mycombobox.Items = sportsCarVehicleStorage
                   .Select(x => x.strVehicleName).ToArray();
```

Make Sure property `strVehicleName` is public in that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` to loop through the list, assigning each member of the list to a named variable, like:

```
foreach (sportsCarVehicle scv in sportsCarVehicleStorage)
{
  //scv is the name of the currently looping sportsCarVehicle object
  //use scv.strVehicleName to access the property.
  myComboBox.Items.Add(scv.strVehicleName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SportsCarVehicle car in myListName)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

That's the most basic example, you can use PLINQ etc. to do it in a more streamlined way.

Comment: Yeah, I was using that structure to pass each instance's name property to the combo box. My problem was that I wouldn't be able to access the name property. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to bind the list of sportsCarVehicle directly to the comboBox, for example:

```
List<sportCarVehicle> sportsCarVehicleStorage= new List<sportsCarVehicle>;

// Set up list content here
// ...

myComboBox.DataSource = sportsCarVehicleStorage;
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "strVehicleName";
```